# What is dev.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, private-beta

If you visit [dev.stackoverflow.com](http://dev.stackoverflow.com/) it says:

> Beta Access
>
> This site is currently in private beta
>   testing.

Is this a new site coming or is it just the test server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have three tiers of development

1. localhost
2. dev
3. production

That is the test server -- development tier. So test locally, then build and deploy to dev, test there, and then if that's good, build and deploy to production.

Comment: I used to be able to get into the test server by faking my cookies but you fixed it now :(

Comment: How do I login to the test server?

Comment: @kinokijuf You don't. It's internal.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the test server.