# How can I join dev.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is dev.stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6041/what-is-dev-stackoverflow-com)

I just found a link to [dev.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/). I tried to login, but got a screen saying this:

> This site is currently in private
>   beta.
>
> It is only visible to users who
>   committed to its Area 51 site proposal
>   ...
>
> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/dev.meta.stackoverflow.com
>
> ...at the moment.
>
> Private betas typically last about 7
>   days. Please come back soon for the
>   public beta!
>
> (If you believe you should have access
>   to this private beta, please email
>   team@stackoverflow.com)

But I [can't find the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/dev.meta.stackoverflow.com) and the private beta has lasted longer than 7 days. I know its the development server, are we even meant to be able to logon to it? I would LOVE to help beta test new features...

[What is dev.stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6041/what-is-dev-stackoverflow-com)

Answer (score 5):

Dev isn't really in private beta. We discourage access to our dev tier.

Comment: Why did you say "discourage" instead of "disallow"? Is it possible - although "discouraged" - to access the dev tier?

Comment: @Kop, if you want to get the hacker badge...

Comment: @kop there's nothing really bad about it, but we just don't guarantee anything about it working, ever

Comment: So how can you get access to it?

Comment: How do I get access?